# How to snooze reminders on the notification screen?

Tags: notifications, ios, reminders

In iOS 7, when a Reminder notification showed up on the Lock screen, I could tap it to Snooze it.  Since I upgraded to iOS 8, the option is no longer there..

Am I missing something simple?  Or is it simply no longer there?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually simple...  Just swipe the notification to the left and you get the Snooze selection.